# Get real-time sensor data from IoT device on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I want to get real-time sensor data from IoT devices using Azure cloud services. This would be displayed on a dashboard for monitoring purposes. What are the options available in Azure?

Comment: You can refer to [Visualize real-time sensor data from your Azure IoT hub in a web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps) and [Tutorial: Visualize real-time sensor data from Azure IoT Hub using Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi)

Comment: Thanks Deep. Are there any managed services from Azure which I can directly use in my JavaScript client side application to fetch real-time sensor data?

Comment: [Azure IoT Hub modules for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/iot-hub?view=azure-node-latest) and [azure-iot-sdk-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node)

Comment: You can also use Azure IoT Central. You can connect your IoT devices and either use IoT Central's built-in customizable dashboards and visualizations, or export the data and use tools such as Azure Data Explorer and Power BI. To get started quickly with IoT Central, take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-central/core/quick-deploy-iot-central

Comment: I was also exploring SignalR service. Can this be an alternative for fetching real-time sensor data from Azure IoT Hub to web applications? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-authenticate-azure-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approach you can try:

1. **Azure IoT-Hub and Azure Data Explorer:** Azure IoT-Hub allows you to connect your devices- and get the real time data from them. And you can then use Azure Data Explorer dashboard to visualize that data.

   Refer: [Ingest data from IoT Hub into Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub)
2. **Azure IoT-Hub and Power BI:** Power BI is a well popular and advance tool for data visualization and analysis and then showing the findings on dashboard.
   Power BI can also integrate with IoT-Hub data.

   Refer: [Using Power BI to visualize real time data from IoT Hub](https://www.electronicwings.com/azure/using-power-bi-to-visualize-real-time-data-from-iot-hub)