# How to send tool data from telemetry Azure IoT Hub to Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I created a room temperature control automation system project based on people's presence using Azure Custom Vision and Raspberry Pi.
I have successfully sent DHT11 temperature sensor data, camera sensors for the number of people in the image to Azure IoT Hub. The next step is how to get data from Azure IoT Hub into Azure Functions and add data to the local database. After that, you can also perform on/off actions on the device being monitored.

My expectation is that after the data can be received by Azure IoT Hub with proof of data in the telemetry message, the data can also be received by Azure Functions, the data can be added to the local database, and with this data Azure Functions can perform actions in the form of on/off to the device monitored.

I have created an event hub, event in azure-iot-hub and i've also created a function from local vscode so that the values ​​from the tool can be entered into the my local database.
My problem was when doing the create an Azure Functions project step and in point number **4. Run the following command to create a Functions app in this folder.**
Link reference: https://github.com/microsoft/IoT-For-Beginners/tree/main/2-farm/lessons/5-migrate-application-to-the-cloud#create-a-serverless-application

My program has an error that can't run as shown in the following image.
[error azure function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDWc.png)
still error like this.
[error azure function 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psRvq.png)

Comment: could you tell what type of code you like use in  Azure Functions like c#, python, etc

Comment: python @Sampath

Comment: In with local db you like to store

Comment: I use a local MySQL database @Sampath

Comment: we have two approaches only  to get data from Azure IoT Hub   Azure Data Explorer and Power BI [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750929/get-real-time-sensor-data-from-iot-device-on-azure)

Comment: note: i only use service Azure IoT Hub, Azure Custom Vision, and Azure Functions. i am not use Azure SQL and Azure MySQL, Azure Stream Analytics because my subscription funds are very limited. i use local database with MySQL languange. after that the data view in Laravel website. @Sampath

Comment: Check the sample code usin local MySQL which I have used to update all event. So we can obtain data from the Azure IoT Hub

Comment: Gets the data and store to local MySQL. In the first image you can see message data  .

Comment: Sorry, I haven't managed to run it @Sampath

Comment: i've already create an Azure Event Hubs trigger for Azure Functions using Visual Studio Code but why my value AzureWebJobsStorage is null? @Sampath

Comment: Code with local MySQL is written where? @Sampath

Comment: Try Code with local MySQL which I have shared it send all the events / modify the according to the requirements.place the code in init.py in visual studio code

Comment: In the above question place some code to send message. So it be approved soon by others.

Comment: If use Azure function on azure/deployed azure you have to migrate to azure sql since local sql will not work on azure.

Comment: May I continue chatting with you via email? I'll ask for more details later. What is your email address? @Sampath

Comment: For now Could please Edit the question with some sample code .I will be more active in stack than in mail. Just raise a new question with IoT hub tag or we chart in comments.

Comment: Hi, I opened the question. Now we chart. share the code in text formate only

Comment: Go to Integration and configure the IoT Hub part  i.e:,  Event Hub name with IoT name

Comment: use `func init MyPythonFunctionApp --python` and `func new` to select the [template](https://i.imgur.com/W2T1So3.png)

Comment: still error, check my question @Sampath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Event Hub [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v1%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python), we can obtain data from the Azure IoT [Hub](https://i.imgur.com/ipJFIOw.png). This function triggers a response to an event sent to an Event Hub event stream.

```py
import logging

from azure.functions import EventHubEvent
from typing import List


def main(events: List[EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                      event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

[image]

- The Azure function below handles events from an Event Hub and inserts the  all event data into a MySQL database. In Azure, we must use Azure SQL and Azure MySQL.
- Connect the Azure Event Hub to the IoT Hub events.
- Create an [event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create) and [storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal) using the Azure portal. Connect the IoT Hub [Events](https://i.imgur.com/riXK9PI.png) to the Endpoint Type and Endpoint of the event hub.

[image]

[image]

**Create an Azure Event Hubs trigger for Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v1%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) using Visual Studio [Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node?pivots=nodejs-model-v4) with the steps below:**

- Select the Azure [function](https://i.imgur.com/SYBjrw1.png) >> Event Hub [trigger](https://i.imgur.com/4n5BGFx.png) >> [functionName](https://i.imgur.com/07HxKtY.png) >> New [setting](https://i.imgur.com/PmXcaOO.png) >> add the Event Hub [created](https://i.imgur.com/TSsLlSt.png)
- Specify the connection string for the Azure Storage account in `local.settings.json` in the AzureWebJobsStorage [Value](https://i.imgur.com/CUE4fJV.png).

**Code with local MySQL:**

```py
from typing import List
import json
import logging
import pymysql
from azure.functions import EventHubEvent

# MySQL connection details
MYSQL_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_USER = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'Password'
MYSQL_DB = 'quickstartdb'

def create_table_if_not_exists(cursor):
    # Define your table schema here
    table_schema = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_data2 (
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            event_data JSON
        )
    """
    cursor.execute(table_schema)

def insert_event_data(cursor, event_data):
    # Insert JSON event data into the table
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO event_data2 (event_data) VALUES (%s)"
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (json.dumps(event_data),))

def main(events: List[EventHubEvent]):
    # Create a MySQL connection
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=MYSQL_HOST,
        user=MYSQL_USER,
        password=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        db=MYSQL_DB,
        charset='utf8mb4',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Create table if not exists
            create_table_if_not_exists(cursor)

            # Process each event
            for event in events:
                event_data = json.loads(event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))

                # Log the event data
                logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s', event_data)

                # Insert JSON event data into MySQL
                insert_event_data(cursor, event_data)

        # Commit the changes
        connection.commit()

    finally:
        # Close the MySQL connection
        connection.close()
```

**Function Logs:**
[image]

[image]

**MySQL:**

[image]

**Another method:**

- Process real-time IoT data streams with Azure Stream Analytics - Azure Stream [Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-get-started-with-azure-stream-analytics-to-process-data-from-iot-devices) with  Azure SQL [Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-db-table) [table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sending-streaming-data-from-azure-iot-central-to-azure-sql-database)

[image]

- Create an IoT Hub data [connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-iot-hub-connection?tabs=portal)  with Azure Data Explorer [Dashboards](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-data-explorer-dashboards-for-iot-data/ba-p/2095138)

[image]

Comment: note: i only use service Azure IoT Hub, Azure Custom Vision, and Azure Functions. i am not use Azure SQL and Azure MySQL, Azure Stream Analytics because my subscription funds are very limited. i use local database with MySQL languange. after that the data view in Laravel website. @Sampath

Comment: Check the sample code usin local 
MySQL  which I have used to update all event. So  we can obtain data from the Azure IoT Hub

Comment: can you give me example or step with photo how to create an IoT Hub events? @Sampath

Comment: Follow this [Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O9jYa_tLHA)

Comment: but i'm use python not c# @Sampath

Comment: I have also added the steps of creating an IoT Hub events answer.

Comment: I have created an event in IoT Hub with the Azure Function endpoint, but the function textbox contains null even though in the Azure function I have created a function. @Sampath

Comment: Create with event hub end point

Comment: can you answer another bug in my little project sir @Sampath? this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792675/how-to-solve-my-message-body-from-iot-device-cant-receive-by-azure-functions-vi