# How to solve my message body from IoT device can't receive by azure functions via vscode/local

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

how to solve this error? this error appear when my sensor detect people and try send data to the cloud.
[error read body from azure function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7A67.png)

> error text:
> this is the result:
> [2024-01-10T09:57:10.295Z] Executing 'Functions.AutomateHubTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=d286be5c-f5e8-4260-9c9e-a6e27de9b87c)
> [2024-01-10T09:57:10.300Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 1, Offset: 4294979360, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2024-01-10T09:55:47.2540000+00:00, SequenceNumber: 110, Count: 1
> [2024-01-10T09:57:10.306Z] Type of body: <class 'list'>, Content of body: [{'id': 'f6acfe2e-8725-2b54-777d-79b477db2796', 'topic': '/SUBSCRIPTIONS/D0E3660E-537C-4385-89F5-B2B0646AF52A/RESOURCEGROUPS/AUTOMATE/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DEVICES/IOTHUBS/AUTOMATE-HUB', 'subject': 'devices/automate-device-id', 'eventType': 'Microsoft.Devices.DeviceTelemetry', 'data': {'properties': {}, 'systemProperties': {'iothub-connection-device-id': 'automate-device-id', 'iothub-connection-auth-method': '{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}', 'iothub-connection-auth-generation-id': '638364984370269801', 'iothub-enqueuedtime': '2024-01-10T09:55:47.0870000Z', 'iothub-message-source': 'Telemetry'}, 'body': 'eyJkYXRlIjogIjIwMjQtMDEtMTAiLCAidGltZSI6ICIxNjo1NTo0NiIsICJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6IDM0LjAsICJwZW9wbGUiOiAwfQ=='}, 'dataVersion': '', 'metadataVersion': '1', 'eventTime': '2024-01-10T09:55:47.087Z'}]
> [2024-01-10T09:57:10.310Z] Executed 'Functions.AutomateHubTrigger' (Failed, Id=d286be5c-f5e8-4260-9c9e-a6e27de9b87c, Duration=15ms)
> [2024-01-10T09:57:10.314Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.AutomateHubTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> Stack:   File "C:\Users\Viqram Wataf\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.24.0\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 406, in _handle__invocation_request
> call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
> File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.9.0\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Viqram Wataf\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.24.0\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 648, in _run_sync_func
> return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
> File "C:\Users\Viqram Wataf\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.24.0\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in *raw_invocation_wrapper
> result = function(**args)
> File "C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas-akhir-project\Tugas-Akhir\azure_function\AutomateHubTrigger_*init**.py", line 29, in main
> date = body['date']

My expectation is that all bodies sent from app.py can be read by the Azure function and can be entered into my local database.
[code body from azure functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUqtx.png)
and insert into my local database.
[insert to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNfYk.png)

this is my atribute table notification in my db.
[atribute db notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xElQ.png)

**init**.py

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import mysql.connector
import time
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
from azure.iot.hub.models import CloudToDeviceMethod
def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):

# Connect database MySQL
dbconnection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    user = "root",
    password = "",
    database = "roomdb"
)
cursor = dbconnection.cursor()

body = json.loads(event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
device_id = event.iothub_metadata.get('automate-device-id')

# logging.info(f'Received message: {body} from {device_id}')

id = 1
date = body['date']
time = body['time']
temperature = body['temperature']
people = body['people']
detect_time = body['last_detected_time']
notification_type = ""
message = "You can view more via website"
room_id = 1
sql = ""

# Insert into database using the notifications
sql = "insert into notifications (id, date, time, value_temperature, number_of_people, notification_type, message, room_id) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
value = (id, date, time, temperature, people, notification_type, message, room_id)

cursor.execute(sql, value)
dbconnection.commit()
print(cursor.rowcount, 'Data Saved Successfully')

cursor.close()
dbconnection.close()
```

Comment: please share the details of the `error read body from azure function`, `code body from azure functions`, and `insert to database`  in the text  also

Comment: ok wait i will add in my question

Comment: please all think above in the question

Comment: could you tell me why you used  ```id = 1
date = body['date']
time = body['time']
temperature = body['temperature']
people = body['people']
detect_time = body['last_detected_time']
notification_type = ""
message = "You can view more via website"```` in your code

Comment: because that's the attribute I use in the notification table in my local db, you can view image in my question @Sampath

Comment: share the error in the text  and share date type, temperature type, etc in SQL or charge the query you used to create the table

Comment: the body type is a list and data type in mySQL query in below:
date('date');
time('time');
double('value_temperature');
integer('number_of_people');
string('notification_type');
string('message');
unsignedBigInteger('room_id');

the error, you can view in my question. @Sampath

Comment: yes I see but if you share in text also form it is easy for me/others to look into it

Comment: change the data format of python like this ``` id = 1
date = body[0]['data']['date']
time = body[0]['data']['time']
temperature = body[0]['data']['value_temperature']
people = body[0]['data']['number_of_people']
detect_time = body[0]['data']['last_detected_time']
notification_type = ""
message = "You can view more via website"
room_id = 1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue concerns a data type mismatch between the received body and the expected data types in your Azure Function code.

- The error message shows a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, which indicates that you are trying to access a list using a string index when your body is a list, not a dictionary.
- The code for sending device telemetry to Azure IoT Hub comes from [DoC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-iot-hub?pivots=programming-language-python).

[image]

[image]

- The values like this:
- Code taken from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77712213/how-to-send-tool-data-from-telemetry-azure-iot-hub-to-azure-functions).

```py
id = 1
date = body[0]['data']['date']
time = body[0]['data']['time']
temperature = body[0]['data']['value_temperature']
people = body[0]['data']['number_of_people']
detect_time = body[0]['data']['last_detected_time']
notification_type = ""
message = "You can view more via website"
room_id = 1
```

[image]